# What is best way to implement shared Queue with workers pushing data and master getting batched data efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue

The use case I am having now is that in a master-worker pipeline, detailed as following:

- For each worker:

  - Retrieve current parameters from master (shared memory parameters)
  - Use the retrieved parameters to generate some data
  - Push the data into kind of shared queue structure
  - Repeat
- For master:

  - Collect a batch of data from the queue, say batch size = 32
  - Use the collected data to update parameters (shared across processes)
  - Repeat

I've tried a naive implementation using Python's build-in multiprocessing's `Process` and `Queue`, however, it seems all workers and the master is competing for accessing the shared queue. Because I was expecting during the workers are asynchronously generating the data and pushing to the queue one by one, the master can retrieve many of data at once, it should be much faster.

But from what I observed, the queue is unbounded to grow, so it seems the master is actually `pop` one entry of data from the queue one at a time, say batch size 32, it performs 32 times of pop function, this is undesired as the asynchronous benefit is diminished.

Is there a better idea how to implement it efficiently ?

Comment: can't really tell you what you are doing wrong without seeing the code, but if all you want to do is multiprocessing then you can try an existing framework such as `dask` which has the additional benefit of being able to run on clusters and not just one machine

Comment: Have you tried using a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` instead, perhaps with [map_async](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map_async)? If order is not important you can use [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async).